# scala, get values from Some(value)

Tags: scala

i am currently trying to read myself into scala. But i got stuck on the following:

```
val value: String = properties(j).attribute("value").toString
print(value)
```

The xml property is read and converted to a string, but gets viewed as "Some(value)". I have tried several things but none seems to work when not i myself created the value with "Option: String"(which was the common solution). Does somebody know an easy way to get rid of the "Some("?

Greetings
Ma

Comment: What should happen when the XML doesn't have a value attribute?

Comment: This is probably a good read for you, the Option type is really common in Scala, worth to get familiar with it: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: try to use `.mkString` if it is available on that object

Answer (score 14):

The value you're calling the toString method on is an `Option[String]` type, as opposed to a plain `String`.  When there is a value, you'll get `Some(value)`, while if there's not a value, you'll get `None`.

Because of that, you need to handle the two possible cases you may get back.  Usually that's done with a match:

```
val value: String = properties(j).attribute("value") match {
  case None => ""//Or handle the lack of a value another way: throw an error, etc.
  case Some(s: String) => s //return the string to set your value
}
```

Comment: Shorter syntax for Map 
// val value = baseMap.getOrElse("value","")

Answer (score 3):

"Some().get" could return the real value.
For example:

```
val m = Map(("1", 2), (3, 4));
val a = m.get("1");
println(a.get + 1);
```

Comment: What does this add to [sumeet agrawal's 2018 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648894)? Is it more helpful than [M.Olmsted's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37888636)?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply get method on Some(value)

```
object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val vanillaDonut: Donut = Donut("Vanilla", 1.50)
    val vanillaDonut1: Donut = Donut("ChocoBar", 1.50,Some(1238L))
    println(vanillaDonut.name)
    println(vanillaDonut.productCode)
    println(vanillaDonut1.name)
    println(vanillaDonut1.productCode.get)

  }

}
case class Donut(name: String, price: Double, productCode: Option[Long] = None)
```

Result:-
Vanilla

None

ChocoBar

1238

Answer (score -1):

Hi and thanks for the input.
I took your code with minor changes, and it was quite confusing with the variables `node.seq, String, Some(String), Some[A]` in the beginning. It works now quite fine with this short version:

```
  val value = properties(j).attribute("value") match {
              case None => ""
              case Some(s) => s //return the string to set your value
            }
```