# How to unwrap Option[MyClassName]?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I am getting a Type mismatch with following error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Color, actual Option[Color]
```

How can I unwrap it?

Below are more details

```
case class ColorDetail(
    color: Option[Color],
    shades: List[Shade]
)

....

colorToProtobuf(colorDetail.color)

....

def colorToProtobuf(c: Color): ColorMessage = {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala, get values from Some(value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884493/scala-get-values-from-somevalue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.get`:

```
case class ColorDetail(
    color: Option[Color],
    shades: List[Shade]
)
val c = ColorDetail(Some(Color("Green")), List())
c.color // Some(Color(Green))
c.color.get // Color(Green)
```

This will fail if `color` is `None` though. If you are okay with that, just let it fail. If you want to give it a default value (ie if a color is not provided), is `.getOrElse(...)`:

```
case class ColorDetail(
    color: Option[Color],
    shades: List[Shade]
)
val c = ColorDetail(None, List())
c.color // None
c.color.getOrElse(Color("Blue")) // Color(Blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Describing a value as `Option` means it may or may be present, and you need to decide what to do in both cases. If you know what the default should be, you can use `getOrElse` as described in other answers. But you can also defer this decision by doing operations that preserve the `Option`.

In your case you can do this:

```
val pb: Option[ColorMessage] = colorDetail.color.map(colorToProtobuf)
```

This will process the `Color` if it is there, but will not cause an error if it is not (it will just return `None`)

You could then do something like

```
val colorMesssage = pb.getOrElse(defaultMessage)
```

Doing it this way means that you don't need to have a default `Color` value, you just need a default `ColorMessage` value.

You can continue to use methods like `map`, `filter` on the option until you are ready to deal with the uncertainty. If you use methods like `contains`, `exists` or `fold` to process the results you may be able to handle the `None` case without needing to invent a "default" value.